# Button dissapears and a photo appears on its place

Tags: java, jbutton, photo

I  have created **JButtons** and what I desire is when I click on them to **disappear**, a **photo** takes its blank space and **revealed**. 
This is a part my **memory card game** but i couldn't find a way to make this in code.. This is what my button listener does until now

```
private class Disappear implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
     int count =0;
        for(int i=0; i<52;i++)
        {
         if(!buttons[i].isVisible())
         {
             count+=1;
         }
        }
        if(count<2)
       ((JButton)e.getSource()).setVisible(false);

        if(count==2)
        {
           for(int i=0; i<52;i++) 
           {
               if(!buttons[i].isVisible())
               {
                   buttons[i].setVisible(true);
               }   
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try using a JToggleButton instead of a regular button. Whenever the JToggleButton is pressed, display a different/new image:

```
class MemGame implements ActionListener(){  

   ImageIcon img  = new ImageIcon("Back.png"); /* Back of the card */  
   ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon("D1.png");   /* Card face */  

   /* Constructor */
   MemGame(){  
      JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Memory Game");
      jfrm.setSize(220, 250);
      jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());  

      JToggleButton jt1 = new JToggleButton(img);  
      jt1.addActionListener(this);  

      jfrm.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Select a card"));  
      jfrm.getContentPane().add(jt1);  
      jfrm.setVisible(true);  
   }  

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){  
      JToggleButton jt = (JToggleButton)ae.getSource();  
      if (!jt.isSelected()) jt.setIcon(img);  
      else jt.setIcon(img2);  
   }
}
```

From here just add logic for handling more than one card pressed, etc.

---

Results
[Before button is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqxht.png)
[After button is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNAaq.png)

---

Credit where credit is due: 
Card images by: whttps://thenounproject.com/term/ace-of-diamonds/170620/
and whttps://thenounproject.com/term/playing-card/146000/

Answer (score 0):

```
   for(int i=0; i<52;i++)
    {
     if(!buttons[i].isVisible())
     {
         count+=1;
     }
    }
    if(count<2)
   ((JButton)e.getSource()).setVisible(false);
```

This logic says "if zero or one buttons are invisible make this button invisible". Is this something you want to achieve? - it seems not.

Then the following loop says "if exactly two buttons were found invisible turn all invisible buttons to visible" - it is your logic

To make "this" button invisible a simple

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
JButton jb=(JButton)e.getSource();
     if(jb.isVisible()) 
   jb.setVisible(false);
}
```

would suffice. Now further with the cards, you may want to have the image attached to the button and show/hide it accordingly. To set the icon to blank you would do

```
      ((JB)e.getSource()).setIcon(null);
```

Read further on image icons